# SVN plugin not available for Eclipse new version(2022-9)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I am trying to use a new version of Eclipse and connect to a SVN server.

I have found that neither Subversive and Subclipe is available to install.

Are they not supported or not recommended to use so only way to use Eclipse and SVN together is using an old version(like Oxygen) of Eclipse?

Update:
I could download Subclipse 4.3.3 and tried to install it directly but it shows the below message...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that for the new Eclipse versions, we don't need SVNKit Client Adapter.
I am not 100% sure but at least to me, I can use SVN(commit/update) without that.

I will leave this post for someone who uses new Eclipse versions and need to access SVN for old projects like it happened to me.

Comment: I have found a better option here ==> https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/eclipse/configuring-svn-and-eclipse/